# How to mount external hard disk every time the server is restarted?

Tags: mount, boot, centos, hard-disk

I have a server which the date will be backup to a external windows server hard disk which is mounted. But problem is every time the server is restarted I will need to mount the disk manually. How do I setup such as it will be mounted on server startup?

Comment: what command do you use to mount it?

Answer (score 2):

you need to put an entry into /etc/fstab

The exact line you put in depends on how you mount the filesystem e.g. is it NFS ,sftp or samba accessed.

Comment: "Windows Server hard disk" I think it's relatively safe to assume he is using samba.